# How to write multiple string in PDFBox with different fonts

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox, java-11

I want to generate a PDF file with multiple Strings: title, subtitle as of now.

- Title: placed at the top of page, centre aligned, font: Times Roman, font size: 18
- Subtitle: placed a little below title, left aligned, font: courier, font size: 14

I am using Apache PDFBox 2.0.21 with Java 11.

I have written the following code:

```
    String title = "Title Goes Here";
    String subTitle = "Subtitle goes here\nTime goes here";
    try(PDDocument document = new PDDocument()){
        PDPage page = new PDPage();

        float px, py;
        int hMargin = 5;
        int vMargin = 10;

        // Writing Title
        PDPageContentStream titleContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false);
        PDFont titleFont = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        float titleFontSize = 18;
        float titleWidth = titleFont.getStringWidth(title)/1000*titleFontSize;
        float titleHeight = titleFont.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight()/1000*titleFontSize;
        titleContentStream.beginText();
        titleContentStream.setFont(titleFont, titleFontSize);
        px = (page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - titleWidth - (2*hMargin))/2;
        py = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - titleHeight - vMargin;
        titleContentStream.newLineAtOffset(px, py);
        titleContentStream.showText(title);
        titleContentStream.endText();
        titleContentStream.close();


        // Writing Subtitle
        PDPageContentStream subtitleContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, false);
        PDFont subtitleFont = PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD;
        float subtitleFontSize = 14;
        float subTitleWidth = subtitleFont.getStringWidth(title)/1000*subtitleFontSize;
        float subTitleHeight = subtitleFont.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight()/1000*subtitleFontSize;
        subtitleContentStream.beginText();
        subtitleContentStream.setFont(subtitleFont, subtitleFontSize);
        px = hMargin;
        py = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - titleHeight - vMargin - subTitleHeight - 5;
        subtitleContentStream.newLineAtOffset(px, py);
        subtitleContentStream.showText(subTitle);
        subtitleContentStream.endText();
        subtitleContentStream.close();

        document.addPage(page);

        document.save("hello.pdf");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

On running the code I am getting following error:

```
Sep 06, 2020 11:03:47 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream <init>
WARNING: You are overwriting an existing content, you should use the append mode
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+000A ('controlLF') is not available in this font Courier-Bold encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
    at org.apache.pdfbox@2.0.21/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.encode(PDType1Font.java:418)
    at org.apache.pdfbox@2.0.21/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:332)
    at org.apache.pdfbox@2.0.21/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showTextInternal(PDPageContentStream.java:514)
    at org.apache.pdfbox@2.0.21/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:476)
    at H2Test/org.Geek8080.Main.main(Main.java:69)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A line feed is not a glyph. You need to do the positioning yourself.

Comment: I am just testing if it works or not, btw thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr That worked for me. Thanks. I thought you were just saying that \n doesn't add new line but turns out that was the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it works. I've flagged your question as a duplicate. The answer I linked to is mostly about TABs, but mentions newlines as well :-)